# What context instance to pass to non-activity constructors from an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

Several classes in Android API require a `Context` parameter in their constructor, for example `ArrayAdapter`, `SQLiteOpenHelper` or `Intent`. When creating such an object from inside an `Activity`, what context instance is more appropriate to pass to them: `this` (the activity instance itself) or the object returned by the activity's `getApplicationContext()` method and why?

Up to now, I have used both and didn't see any difference in the resulting functionality. Is there any rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of `getApplicationContext()` method:

> Return the context of the single, global Application object of the
>   current process. This generally should only be used if you need a
>   Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is
>   tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

> Consider for example how this interacts with {@ #registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)}:
>
> - If used from an Activity context, the receiver is being registered
>     within that activity. This means that you are expected to unregister
>     before the activity is done being destroyed; in fact if you do not do
>     so, the framework will clean up your leaked registration as it removes
>     the activity and log an error. Thus, if you use the Activity context
>     to register a receiver that is static (global to the process, not
>     associated with an Activity instance) then that registration will be
>     removed on you at whatever point the activity you used is destroyed.
> - If used from the Context returned here, the receiver is being
>     registered with the global state associated with your application.
>     Thus it will never be unregistered for you. This is necessary if the
>     receiver is associated with static data, not a particular component.
>     However using the ApplicationContext elsewhere can easily lead to
>     serious leaks if you forget to unregister, unbind, etc.